# Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty error

Tags: asp.net, json, api

I have this json format I'm making an API using ASP.NET.

```json
{
  "0": {
    "order_id": 11748,
    "complete_date": "2021-04-19 14:48:41",
    "shipping_code": "aramex.aramex",
    "awbs": [
      {
        "aramex_id": "1314",
        "order_id": "11748",
        "awb_number": "46572146154",
        "reference_number": "11748",
        "date_added": "2021-03-04 03:46:58"
      }
    ],
    "payment": {
      "method": {
        "name": "الدفع عند الاستلام",
        "code": "cod"
      },
      "invoice": [
        {
          "code": "sub_total",
          "value": "120.8700",
          "value_string": "120.8700 SAR",
          "title": "الاجمالي"
        },
        {
          "code": "shipping",
          "value": "0.0000",
          "value_string": "0.0000 SAR",
          "title": "ارمكس"
        },
        {
          "code": "coupon",
          "value": "-13.9000",
          "value_string": "-13.9000 SAR",
          "title": "قسيمة التخفيض(RMP425)"
        },
        {
          "code": "cashon_delivery_fee",
          "value": "5.0000",
          "value_string": "5.0000 SAR",
          "title": "رسوم الدفع عند الاستلام"
        },
        {
          "code": "tax",
          "value": "18.1300",
          "value_string": "18.1300 SAR",
          "title": " ضريبة القيمة المضافة (15%)"
        },
        {
          "code": "total",
          "value": "130.1000",
          "value_string": "130.1000 SAR",
          "title": "الاجمالي النهائي"
        }
      ]
    },
    "product": [
      {
        "id": 69,
        "name": "مخلط 4 أو دو بيرفيوم للجنسين - 100 مل",
        "sku": "45678643230",
        "weight": "0.50000000",
        "quantity": 1,
        "productDiscount": "",
        "images": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I reach `order_id`? I made an object let's say its name is obj1 I tried foreach obj1 and storing into a variable `obj1.order_id;`
It stored null in the variable. the {"0"} is the numbering of orders starts 0-1-2 etc.

[image]

Comment: Deserialize this json into a `Dictionary<string,Order>` where `Order` class has a property of `int order_id`

Comment: @Omar check my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`deserialize`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) that json to `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` without creating a new class as following:

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);

var orderId = values["0"]["order_id"].ToString();
```

This will give you `11748` as a result.